# how to make a new key value pair in r

Tags: r, json

I have two arrays, period and count like below

```
period <- c("01-12-2017", "01-01-2018", "01-02-2018", "01-03-2018" ,"01-04-2018" ,"01-05-2018")
```

and

```
count <- c(13, 11, 8, 11, 13, 10)
```

I want it in a format of a json like below

```
{"01-12-2017":"13","01-01-2018":"11","01-02-2018":"8","01-03-2018":"11","01-04-2018":"13","01-05-2018":"10"}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick (using the package `jsonlite)`

```
# convert count to character as that is the expected value in desired output
jsonlite::toJSON(as.list(setNames(as.character(count), period)), 
                 auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
# {
#   "01-12-2017": "13",
#   "01-01-2018": "11",
#   "01-02-2018": "8",
#   "01-03-2018": "11",
#   "01-04-2018": "13",
#   "01-05-2018": "10"
# }
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use  `paste0(period, ":", count)`

Comment: Nice and simple. But you also need to put quotes around the values to match the expected output in the question